# I need to update the wc_price in cart through ajax it is only updating on refreshing the page in wordpress?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, cart

**I need to make the wc_price update through ajax call. It is only updating refreshing the page.**

```
<div class="cpops-drawer-header">
    <?php do_action( 'cartpops_drawer_header' ); ?>
</div>

<div class="cpops-drawer-cart">
    <?php do_action( 'cartpops_drawer_cart_contents' ); ?>
</div>
<?php
   $min_amount = 300; //change this to your free shipping threshold
   $current = WC()->cart->subtotal_ex_tax;
   if ( $current < $min_amount ) {
       echo '<span class="min_amount_class" id="min_amount_class" style="color:#ac192b;font-weight:bold;font-size:18px">Get free shipping if you order ' . wc_price( $min_amount - $current ) . ' more before taxes!</span>';
   }
?>
<div class="cpops-drawer-footer">
    <?php do_action( 'cartpops_drawer_coupon_form' ); ?>
    <?php do_action( 'cartpops_drawer_recommendations' ); ?>
    <?php do_action( 'cartpops_drawer_totals' ); ?>
    <?php do_action( 'cartpops_powered_by' ); ?>
</div>
```